# Excel array formula not working

Tags: arrays, excel

I have a list of 500 clinics in column B and their service numbers in column AC. The data starts at row 6. On a separate worksheet I would like to extract a list of the clinics with zero services.

I know I need to use an array formula but I'm struggling to get it to work. I'm using CTRL, Shift, Enter so it's not as simple as this.

This is what I have so far:

```
{=IFERROR(INDEX('LAPM and SAPAC services
 (2017)'!$B$6:$B$505,SMALL(IF('LAPM and SAPAC services
 (2017)'!$AC$6:$AC$505="0",ROW('LAPM and SAPAC services
 (2017)'!$B$6:$B$505)-ROW('LAPM and SAPAC services
 (2017)'!$B$6)+1),ROWS('LAPM and SAPAC services 
 (2017)'!$B$6:$B6))),"")}
```

Can anyone explain where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Zero services is a number.

Comment: Fixed it. Removed the quotation marks around the 0. Thank you.